# How to send data to client with conn.send()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Im trying to create a simple chat server. I've been able to send information to the server through the client using 'client.send()' but I cannot seem to do the same server->client

I have tried using methods such as conn.send() and conn.sendall(), but (I guess since the code is in a try) they seem to get skipped after the initial conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))

Server code

```py
import socket
from _thread import *
import sys

server = "192.168.0.4"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2)
print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")


def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))
    reply = ""
    while True:
        conn.send(str.encode(str(reply)))
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048*1)
            reply = data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                print("Disconnected")
                break
            else:
                print("Received: ", reply)
                print("Sending : ", reply)

            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply)) #Where I want to send information to the client
        except:
            break

    print("Lost connection")
    conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to:", addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

client code

```py
import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
      self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      self.server = "192.168.0.4"
      self.port = 5555
      self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
      self.id = self.connect()
      print(self.id)

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

```py
from network import Network
n = Network()

while True:
    n.send("sending stuff") #this works/sends properly
```

Comment: you forgot to display it `print( n.send("sending stuff") )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `print()` to display data from server

```
while True:
    print( n.send("sending stuff") )
```

BTW: in server you send the same data two times - with `conn.send()` and `conn.sendall()`